# Converting AVL to SLD or QML file

Tags: convert, sld, arcview-3, qml

Is there a simple way to convert an AVL file into an SLD or QML file?
deegree does not work an my laptop (Java problems)

Or is there a way to open the original AVL file in QGIS?

Comment: i don't get it working! how do i run this in qgis?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: This script worked perfectly for me. It converted a polygon thematic map with plain solid colours for each category. It gave a better output than going via Arc2Earth in ArcGIS which I have used previously. From the Windows command line I omitted the initial 'python' so just > avl2qml.py pathtothe.avl pathtothenew.qml Thank you, Snorfalorpagus!

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've written a small python script to convert ArcView 3.x Legends (.AVL) to QGIS styles (.QML):

https://github.com/snorfalorpagus/avl2qml

You can download the current version here:

https://github.com/snorfalorpagus/avl2qml/archive/master.zip

To use: `python avl2qml.py pathtothe.avl pathtothenew.qml`

It's only had limited testing, but I've had some good results with it.

Comment: Sorry, i did not check in here for a while.

Comment: Hi, I tried it, but there was an error "unexpected end of file in Line 1, Columme 1". However, I never used Python before and there were several error messages: No Module named pyobd. When trying to install pyodb "Unable to find vcvarsall". Got Python only with ArcMap, never installed it alone.

Comment: works like magic

Comment: @Snorfalorpagus.I was able to convert an avl file for styling linestrings. Great! No I have one for Polygons and I get the following ERROR: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "avl2qml.py", line 303, in <module>
    qml = avl2qml(data, shapefile=args.shp[0], field_name=args.field[0])
  File "avl2qml.py", line 16, in avl2qml
    odb = pyodb.ODB(data)
  File "d:\avl2qml-master\pyodb.py", line 36, in __init__
    obj.resolve_references()
  File "d:\avl2qml-master\pyodb.py", line 163, in resolve_references
    self.outlinewidth = self.attrs['OutlineWidth']
KeyError: 'OutlineWidth'`

Comment: I tested it, unfortunately, the created .qml didn't work.